# CDO select variable in parallel

Tags: netcdf, cdo-climate

I want to select/split a specific variable `TT` from a big NetCDF file using the `CDO` library/package in parallel to speed up the process.

I used the following:

```
cdo -P 8 select,name=TT infile.nc outfile_TT.nc
```

but got the following error:

```
-bash: cdo -P: command not found
```

I have tried also  `-selname` and `-select` as operators but it gives me the same error.

It only works when I run it in serial (i.e., remove `-P 8`) as follows:

```
cdo select,name=TT infile.nc outfile_TT.nc
```

Is it possible to run this in parallel using `CDO`?

Comment: According to the CDO documentation (Appendix B, https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/embedded/cdo.pdf#page=220&zoom=100,94,70) parallel processing is not supported for select operator.

Answer (score 1):

According to the CDO documentation ([Appendix B - Parallelized operators](https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/embedded/cdo.pdf#page=220&zoom=100,94,70)) parallel processing is not supported for `select` operator.